# Power BI ADAL authentication

Tags: android, azure, active-directory, powerbi, adal

Hello I'm trying to use Power BI API with android but i'm getting some troubles

i already did Azure active directory authentication

after i login i get something like this

```
06-28 13:00:20.463 6274-6274/telmex.blitz.com.telmexpowerbi D/LoginPowerBI: ID Token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.eyJhdWQiOiIyYTMzOWZiMy0xM2M0LTQxZjktODMyZS0....
06-28 13:00:20.463 6274-6274/telmex.blitz.com.telmexpowerbi D/LoginPowerBI: Access Token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI6IkFRQUJBQUFBQUFCbmZpRy1tQTZOVGFlN0NkV1c3UWZkSkVncDBz...
Expires On: Wed Jun 28 14:00:19 CDT 2017
```

so i'm using retrofit to consume Power BI API

```
header --> callReports.request().header("Authorization: Bearer "+accessToken);
```

but when i'm trying to get my reports i get

```
raw response --> Response{protocol=http/1.1, code=403, message=Forbidden, url=https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/reports}
```

permissions

[image: PowerBI Permissions]

i already have PowerBI and Sign in and Access the directory as the signed-in user permission

what else do i need or what could i've done wrong?

Comment: Does your signed-in user have access to Power BI? 403 usually means "We know who you are but you are not authorized to view this".

Comment: @juunas yes it has, I already tested it with apiary

Answer (score 0):

According to your error code & resource url, I think the issue was caused by missing the required permission when you did the request for reading reports , the possible reason of `403` code as the figure below from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#use-the-access-token-to-access-the-resource).

[image]

So you need to check and add the required permission via Azure portal and PowerBI, as below.

1. On Azure portal, add the `Power BI service` permission in the settings tab of your registed app of Azure AD, please see the figure below

[image]

2. Follow the step 6 of the section `Register with the Power BI App Registration Tool` of the document [`Register an app to embed Power BI content`](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-register-app/) to check and add the required Power BI permissions.

Then try again. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks but I already have all of them that why i don't understand what's going on (Added picture on post):(